# Query Question to retrieve sub folders / subset lists

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, automationstudio, email-studio

Is there a query activity to query Publication Lists to find out what the subfolders are and the lists they contain?

If I do this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT (ls.ListName) AS 'ListName'
, ls.ListID as 'ListID'
, ls.ListType AS 'ListType'
    FROM _ListSubscribers ls
```

It returns all the publication lists including the lists in the sub folders but the result set does not tell me the sub folder names or which list is in the sub folder- all the lists in the subfolders are of ListType = "Publication List"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is no such column in the data view that is accessible using a query activity there is no possibility to get this information from a query.

Information on available columns can be found in the [documentation about the ListSubscribers Data View](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/data_views/data_view_listsubscribers/).

Answer (score 1):

As Markus explained, there is no column in the system data view that stores the folder information.  However, this information is stored in the corresponding API object. The attribute name is Category ID.

The link below provide a example of retrieving a list using the API. To retrieve all lists for a specific category id, you would need to replace the filter statement in the code.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_a_list_from_an_account.htm